# Installing django-eav on Django 1.10 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to install 'django-eav' to my project. I made sure to have `'django.contrib.sites'` in my `settings.py` file. I installed it using `pip install -e git+git://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav.git#egg=django-eav`. But when I try to add `'eav'` in my `settings.py`, it says that it is an unresolved reference. The installation creates a directory in my project directory with the name `src`. The directory has a text file which says

This file is placed here by pip to indicate the source was put
here by pip.

Once this package is successfully installed this source code will be
deleted (unless you remove this file).

I guess that there's some problem with my installation. Please help!

Comment: First things first. Here's the link to the `pip install` documentation: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

Comment: I was able to properly install `django-eve`... Could you copy and paste the complete python stack traceback?

Comment: Did you ever determine the issue?